# AngularJS uigrid Checkbox column Header name

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

Can I add header Name for default checkbox column in uigrid? If so how can I do that?

[image]

Comment: yes you can. you can close this question or add your code or demo in Plunker

Comment: Sorry, it seems my question was incomplete,can you tell me how can I do that?

Comment: post relevant code where you configure ui-grid `options`

Comment: enabling checkbox in uigrid is just a simple set of code

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer you override the ng-template of the ui-grid header. This is just a hack.

```
.ui-grid-header-viewport {
    .ui-grid-header-cell {
        .ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        .ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons:before {
            content: 'checkme!';
        }
    }
}
```